# python tuple and enum

Tags: python, enums, tuples

So I was trying to use enums in python and came upon the following error:
When I was using enum as a tuple and giving it two values, I can't access only one value such as `tuple[0]`

```
class Rank(Enum):
    ACE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 4
    FIVE = 5
    SIX = 6
    SEVEN = 7
    EIGHT = 8
    NINE = 9
    TEN = 10
    JACK = 11
    QUEEN = 12
    KING = 13, "King"

print (Rank.KING.value)
```

and the print is

> (13, 'King')

How can I access only one value so I can print 13 or 'King'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the following possibilites to access 13 or "king":

```
Rank.KING.value[0]
Rank.KING.value[1]
```

Answer (score 15):

With `enum.Enum`, the class variable names themselves become the `name` attribute of the enumerated attributes of the `Enum` instance, so you don't have to make `KING` a tuple of value and name:

```
class Rank(Enum):
    King = 13

print(Rank.King.name) # outputs 'King'
print(Rank.King.value) # outputs 13
```

If you want to name the class variables with capital letters but have their `name` values to be mixed-cased, which isn't what `Enum` is designed for, you would have to subclass `Enum` and override the `name` method yourself to customize the behavior:

```
from enum import Enum
from types import DynamicClassAttribute

class MixedCaseEnum(Enum):
    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def name(self):
        return self._name_.title()

class Rank(MixedCaseEnum):
    KING = 13

print(Rank.KING.name) # outputs 'King'
print(Rank.KING.value) # outputs 13
```

Answer (score 10):

None of the existing answers explained how you might have three (or more) values in an Enum, if you wanted to.

For example, say the initial questioner wanted `(13, "K", "king")` in the Enum, they would do it like this:

```py
class Rank(Enum):
    K = 13, "King"

    def __init__(self, rank, label):
        self.rank = rank
        self.label = label
```

The `__init__` takes the values and assigns them to the enum members. This means that `Rank.K.rank` returns `13` and `Rank.K.label` returns `"King"`.

Although it's not strictly needed in this example, it can be useful to store more than key/value pairs on the Enum.

Note that `Rank.K.value` still exists, and returns the tuple `(13, "King")`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. One thing I realized is that you cannot define a member `name`, because it would conflict with `Enum.name`. The same way that `Rank.K.value` still exists, `Rank.K.name` does too.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use indexes as you would use them on an array:

```
>>> KING = 13, 'King'
>>> KING
(13, 'King')
>>> KING[0]
13
>>> KING[1]
'King'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna preserve `.value` initial funcionality, you can use `Enum.__new__()`.

```python
class Rank(int, Enum):
    QUEEN = 12
    KING = 13, 'King'

    def __new__(cls, value, label='...'):
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.label = label
        return obj

print(Rank.QUEEN.label)
print(Rank.KING.label)
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#when-to-use-new-vs-init